# How can I use MacVim like gVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to get a Mac Vim setup similar to my Windows gVim setup. I downloaded homebrew and installed Macvim with it, but when I run MacVim it comes up in a terminal and looks like regular Vim.

All I did in Windows was download gVim and I got some vimrc settings from a popular github repository so everything looks nicer and plugins were all set up for me. How can I achieve something similar with Mac?

I am relatively new to both Mac and Vim so help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you running macvim? `mvim` should open an actual gui.

Answer (score -1):

MacVim comes with two executables: one is a regular windowed GUI application and the other is a command-line program. Both are bundled in the MacVim.app that you downloaded and installed in `~/Applications`.

Double-clicking on the icon in the finder, clicking on the icon in the dock or choosing MacVim from the "Open with…" contextual menu should start the GUI.

---

Using someone else's setup is a ***very*** bad idea. Don't.